# Get return value from function called inside With...End With Statement

Tags: vb6

In one of my event, i'm using "With...End With Statement", so i need to take the return value from a method that used inside the "With...End With Statement"

With my first way, i can take the return value like

```
Dim RetVal As MyApp.ErrorConstants
RetVal = AgentApp.Login(txtUserName, txtPassword, txtStation)
```

after that i'm gonna change my code to With...End With Statement" , and how to get the return value

```
Dim RetVal As MyApp.ErrorConstants

With AgentApp
    .Login txtUserName, txtPassword, txtStation
    .DisplayMessages = 0
    .UISettings.SuppressErrors = False
    .UISettings.SuppressMessages = False
End With
```

Answer (score 3):

we can try like this

```
Dim RetVal As MyApp.ErrorConstants

With AgentApp
   RetVal = .Login(txtUserName, txtPassword, txtStation)
    .DisplayMessages = 0
    .UISettings.SuppressErrors = False
    .UISettings.SuppressMessages = False
End With
```